# How to get value inside file upload textbox from database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page where the user can edit the previously uploaded file by uploading a new file and edit the file name and details of the file. I am stuck in getting the file value from the database. 
How do I get the URL/value from database and display in upload URL textbox?

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label for="file" class="label required">Upload File</label>
                    <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file" multiple="multiple" value= @Html.EditorFor(model => model[i].upload_url) />
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While uploading file you can use code similar to below:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file) {

  if (file.ContentLength > 0) {
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);

    //// Save this fileName somewhere in Database


   //// save this file somewhere in database (which you probably are doing already)
  }

}
```

Then while showing the last uploaded file,  you can render the fileName in that upload file text box.

Please note that if you have not saved file name or original path (depending on your requirement) you will not be able to show it.